# How do I prevent an endless Listview scroll of product data being repeated on my product screens? [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, duplicates, scrollview, flutter-listview

I'm working on a shopping app for a school project, and I'm trying to get my product images and details to show up on the various product detail screens. I used some sample images from flutter's Shrine sample app as I followed their tutorial. The problem I'm facing now is an endless Listview scroll that looks like this, and when you keep scrolling, it repeats the image and details endlessly:
[image]

What should I do to avoid this? Sorry, I am really new to coding so I am not to sure how to go about fixing this problem...Below I have included a few dart files of my current code which might be helpful. Thank you to anyone who is willing to help, it is very much appreciated!

Product detail screen dart file:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:MyShoppingApp/provider/CartProvider.dart';
import 'package:MyShoppingApp/db/cart_database.dart';
import 'package:MyShoppingApp/model/cart.dart';
import 'model/products_repository.dart';
import '../model/cart.dart';


class ProductDetailsPage extends StatelessWidget {

  static const routeName = '/user-products';
   ProductDetailsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key); //const
  DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //get particular productId using the ModalRoute class
    final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
    print(productId);
    //use Provider package to find out ID by accessing method declared in Product()
    final loadedProduct = ProductsRepository().findById(productId);
   
    //List<bool> clicked = List.generate(10, (index) => false, growable: true);
      final cart = Provider.of<CartProvider>(context);
      void saveData(int index) {
        dbHelper
            .insert(
          CartItem(
            id: index,
            title: loadedProduct.name,
            price: loadedProduct.price.toDouble(),
            quantity: ValueNotifier(1),
            image: loadedProduct.image,
          ),
        )
            .then((value) {
          cart.addTotalPrice(loadedProduct.price.toDouble());
          cart.addCounter();
          print('Product Added to cart');
        }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
          print(error.toString());
        });
      }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange[50],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange[900],
        title: const Text("Product details "),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
            color: Colors.black,
            semanticLabel: 'back to home',
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
        //body:
        body: ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 8.0),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: loadedProduct.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                //SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 300,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        loadedProduct.image,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Text(
                      '\$${loadedProduct.price}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Colors.blueGrey.shade900),
                        onPressed: () {
                          saveData(Random().nextInt(1000));
                        },
                        child: const Text('Add to Cart')),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Text(
                        loadedProduct.description,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        softWrap: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            })
    );
  }
  }
```

Product Repository Dart file:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:MyShoppingApp/db/cart_database.dart';
//add product data
import 'package:MyShoppingApp/model/product.dart';

//to get all products at once or any particular product by its ID
//product class that uses mixins with ChangeNotifier
class ProductsRepository with ChangeNotifier {
  DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper();

  static List<Product> loadProducts(Category category) {
    //linked list storing objects of type Product
    var allProducts = <Product>[
      Product(
        category: Category.accessories,
        id: "0",
        isFeatured: true,
        name: 'Vagabond sack',
        price: 120,
        details: "Nice fancy shirt",
        description: "Comfortable and minimalistic",
        image: "packages/shrine_images/0-0.jpg",
      ),
      Product(
        category: Category.accessories,
        id: "1",
        isFeatured: true,
        name: 'Stella sunglasses',
        price: 58,
        details: "",
        description: "",
        image: "packages/shrine_images/1-0.jpg",
      ),
      Product(
        category: Category.accessories,
        id: "2",
        isFeatured: false,
        name: 'Whitney belt',
        price: 35,
        details: "",
        description: "",
        image: "packages/shrine_images/2-0.jpg",
      ),
      Product(
        category: Category.accessories,
        id: "3",
        isFeatured: true,
        name: 'Garden strand',
        price: 98,
        details: "",
        description: "",
        image: "packages/shrine_images/3-0.jpg",
      ),
      Product(
        category: Category.accessories,
        id: "4",
        isFeatured: false,
        name: 'Strut earrings',
        price: 34,
        details: "",
        description: "",
        image: "packages/shrine_images/4-0.jpg",
      ),//removed other products to save space
    ];

    if (category == Category.all) {
      return allProducts;
    } else {
      return allProducts.where((Product p) {
        return p.category == category;
      }).toList();
    }
  }

  //to get particular products by ID
  Product findById(String id) {
    var x = loadProducts(Category.all).firstWhere((prod) => prod.id == id);
    print("findById successful");
    print(x);
    return x;
  }
  
  void addProduct() {
    // _items.add(value);
    notifyListeners();
  }

}
```

Thank you everyone! Also, this problem stemmed from an earlier error in another post that a user was helping me to work through, but I didn't want to trouble them too much so I am reposting it here. Thank you @eamirho3ein

Comment: For me it is strange that findById() returns a product.  And the list is passed loadedProduct.length as itemCount. This should not be possible, because loadedProduct is not an iterable (in your case I think a List to Product). Does your Product class have a variable length? Or is this somehow not the actual code?

Comment: @OzanTaskiran Thank you for your help! Yes I actually followed a shopping cart tutorial online so maybe I copied `loadedproduct.length` as an unnecessary line of code. I just tried commenting that line out but the problem still persisted unfortunately

Comment: But then you wouldn't need a listview, you just want to show a detail page for a product or am I wrong? A ListView makes sense if you want to display several elements below each other or next to each other, e.g. in a to-do list.

Comment: And actually, it shouldn't let you compile at all if you call the .length on a product. Probably there is a length variable programmed into your product model class.

Comment: @OzanTaskiran Thank you! Right, I wouldn't need a listview - I just wasn't sure what to put for a scrollable detail page. Instead of a listview what is a more suitable constructor to use here?

Comment: Wrap it inside a SingleChildScrollView :D

Comment: Thank you! Would I replace `body: ListView.builder(` with `body: SingleChildScrollView(`? also how would I change `itemBuilder: (context, index)` for SingleChildScrollView? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, replace the ListView with SingleChildScrollView. You have to remove the itemBuilder, it is a part of the ListView. Place your builder content as a child from SingleChildScrollView.

Comment: @OzanTaskiran Thank you for your reply. However, I need to `context` and `index` from my product detail page so that I will not cause an undefined error. How would I go about doing so once I remove itemBuilder?

Comment: You don't need your index anymore. You show just 1 product on the page, your findById function returns only 1 product. It's not a list, it is a single object.  The only place you use your index is the saveData function. But you can just pass the id of product. Did the project even compile? Because you pass a int to the saveData function, but save the int (the index) as product id. But the product id is a String, not an int. I don't understand how this should be possible ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class ProductDetailsPage extends StatefulWidget {

  static const routeName = '/user-products';
   ProductDetailsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key); 
  @override
  State<ProductDetailsPage> createState() => _ProductDetailsPageState();
}

class _ProductDetailsPageState extends State<ProductDetailsPage> {
 //const
  DBHelper dbHelper = DBHelper();
  List<Product> loadedProduct = []; // <----update this

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      //get particular productId using the ModalRoute class
      final productId = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
      print(productId);
      //use Provider package to find out ID by accessing method declared in Product()
      setState(() {
         loadedProduct = ProductsRepository().findById(productId);
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    
    //List<bool> clicked = List.generate(10, (index) => false, growable: true);
      final cart = Provider.of<CartProvider>(context);
      void saveData(int index) {
        dbHelper
            .insert(
          CartItem(
            id: index,
            title: loadedProduct.name,
            price: loadedProduct.price.toDouble(),
            quantity: ValueNotifier(1),
            image: loadedProduct.image,
          ),
        )
            .then((value) {
          cart.addTotalPrice(loadedProduct.price.toDouble());
          cart.addCounter();
          print('Product Added to cart');
        }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
          print(error.toString());
        });
      }

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.orange[50],
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange[900],
        title: const Text("Product details "),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
            color: Colors.black,
            semanticLabel: 'back to home',
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
      ),
        //body:
        body: ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 8.0),
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: loadedProduct.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                //SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 300,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        loadedProduct.image,
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 10),
                    Text(
                      '\$${loadedProduct.price}',
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            primary: Colors.blueGrey.shade900),
                        onPressed: () {
                          saveData(Random().nextInt(1000));
                        },
                        child: const Text('Add to Cart')),
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Text(
                        loadedProduct.description,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        softWrap: true,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this following error after doing so: The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'List<dynamic>'. The same error comes up for price, image, description, etc. It suggests that I create a local variable "name" but I don't think that's what I'm going for if I have already defined loadedproducts. Thank you so much for your help again @eamirho3ein! You have helped me so much and I really owe it to you!

Comment: I updated my answer, check it out, hope it fixes it

Comment: Hmm... I got another similar error: The getter 'name' isn't defined for the type 'List<Product>'. (Instead of List<dynamic> it's List<Product>) I think maybe I need to make some changes to the Product Repository file? But my getter are all defined there so far

Comment: It is very odd  that not recognizing Product.

Comment: Yes...I have tried undoing all the edits, it seems that with the previous code did not have any trouble recognizing Product after adding this `List<Product> loadedProduct = [];` but for some reason with this new code it does not recognize it. I have tried changes this placement of `List<Product> loadedProduct = [];` and checking if I have imported the necessary dart files, but it did not fix the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Hello I see some weird thing there.

`ProductsRepository().findById(productId)` return a single `Product`. Then
`loadedProduct` is a `Product`. Later on the `ListView.builder` on the `itemCount` parameter you used `loadedProduct.length` (`loadedProduct` in this point is used as a list of element). I dont know if the `Product` object have a `.length` method nor what returns that. But i think there is the problem. When you set `itemCount: loadedProduct.length` you are saying than the list will have ***x*** elements and  later on the `itemBuilder` you are only using the data from `loadedProduct` to create the same widget in the list, ***x*** times.

Assuming that `loadedProduct.length = 10`, you will have a list view with the same Element 10 times

The next example use the `loadedProduct` to fill the `products` list. The `product` list will be used as the data on the `ListView.builder`. Then the list will show 3 time the same widget.

```
final products = [
  loadedProduct,
  loadedProduct,
  loadedProduct
];
return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.orange[50],
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange[900],
      title: const Text("Product details "),
      leading: IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(
          Icons.arrow_back_ios_outlined,
          color: Colors.black,
          semanticLabel: 'back to home',
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    ),
    //body:
    body: ListView.builder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 8.0),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: products.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final targetProduct = products[index];
          return Card(
            //SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 300,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Image.asset(
                    targetProduct.image,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                Text(
                  '\$${targetProduct.price}',
                  style: const TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: Colors.blueGrey.shade900),
                    onPressed: () {
                      saveData(Random().nextInt(1000));
                    },
                    child: const Text('Add to Cart')),
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Text(
                    targetProduct.description,
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    softWrap: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        })
);
```

Just think what do you want to show on the list and use the right data. And review why the `Product` object have a `.length` method and what it return.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I see what you mean. I have tried commenting our product.length to test it and the problem still persists.

Comment: Could you explain me what do you want to show on the list?. Because if you want to show only 1 element you don't need a ListView. In other hand of you want to show a list of product then you need to load the data from other thing, not from loadedProduct.

Comment: Yes, I think I don't need a listview, but I want to show one product image and product details (like name, price, description, etc.) on a scrollable page. What constructor would be useful for that? This page is navigated from the home page where there are a list of products. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You could use a `SingleChildScrollView`, this widget will allow to use scroll. The widget have a parameter `child`, here you could put a new widget that could be larger than scroll and the `SingleChildScrollView` will handle the page scrolling, or you could use as `child` a `Column` this widget will allow you to show many things on the screen without problems. 
Example: `SingleChildScrollView( child: Column( children: [Container(....),SizedBox(...),Container(...),Text(....)],),)`

Answer (score -2):

if you want to stop scroll listview add
**NeverScrollableScrollPhysics**

```
physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

Inside ListView widget, use